# Работа с jar-файлами

Tags: jar, java, zip

Программа на java. Использует 2 текстовых файла .txt. При запуске джар из командной строки он ищет этий файлы в локальной папке диска, а нужно, чтобы всё было вместе. Как заставить его смотреть эти файлы в джарнике? Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно упаковать файлы в тот же jar и получать к ним доступ через `Class.getResourceAsStream(String name)`:

Пример из http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/read-text-file-from-jar-file

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("3Columns.csv");
```